# Where is TeXworks' syntax-pattern.txt file (on windows 7)?

Tags: highlighting, texworks

I was trying to change my TeXworks editor's background to black, some suggested it is possible to edit this file :

```
~/.TexWorks/configuration/syntax-pattern.txt
```

but I could not locate this .txt file.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That path is a Unix(-like) path, and unlikely to exist on Windows. Can't you just search for `syntax-pattern.txt`?

Comment: @jon I tried the search at Windows start, but no result turned up.

Comment: Looks like the manual is available on Google Drive, the link to which is available [here](http://www.tug.org/texworks/).  I use neither Windows nor TeXworks, so I need to stop here.  Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows, with MiKTeX 2.9 distribution, you can get the required file on the following path:

```
"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\TeXworks\0.4\configuration\syntax-patterns.txt"
```

Of course `Username` is your Windows user name.

Note also that this file is not for background colors but for text syntax highlighting. You can find more details in [this link](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=6921) on how to customize colors and syntax highlighting.

Comment: For others: note that the colors are described in words (Google [`css colors`](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+colors) in order to get a list of what's available). The code after the color (such as `\\(?:[A-Za-z@]+|.)`) is to do with which characters escape the color mode (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Whilst a different Windows version and TeXworks installer, I found the `syntax-pattern.txt` file on Windows 10 when installed with TeX Live 2021 in this directory:

`C:\Users\[Your user]\.texlive2021\texmf-config\texworks\configuration\`

[image]

Came across this question but the accepted answer was not helpful for TeX Live hence this answer.