# How can I set a dark theme in TeXworks?

Tags: texworks

I am trying to set a dark theme in TeXworks.
This is similar to the question
"[How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio)",
but with the IDE TeXworks instead of TeXstudio.

The output should look similar to the following:

[image]

(Of course, it should look like TeXworks rather than TeXstudio.)

Is what I am asking possible?

Comment: There seems to be an issue for that on GitHub: https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/164.

Comment: I get the dark mode in my texworks, however, it shows only when open cliking on the textworks.exe (direct access), if I have any file with textworks extension and cliking dark mode does not work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I managed to figure this out by combining answers from two sources.

First, I found a post on the topic "[Customize Editor Colors](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=6921#)".
The author of the post explains that you should create 
a custom style sheet `mystyle.css` using CSS mark-up,
with the contents:

```
QTextEdit {
    background-color: black;  
    color: white;            /* sets the main text color */
}
```

When you run TeXworks from the command line,
with the optional argument telling TeXworks to use that CSS file,

```
> texworks -stylesheet /pathto/mystyle.css
```

then the TeXworks editor shows white text on a black background:

[image]

Normally, I start TeXworks by clicking on a button on the Windows taskbar.
I can edit the button/shortcut so that
TeXworks loads the CSS file when it starts up as follows:

1. `Shift` + `right click` on the button
2. Click `Properties`
3. Change

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-texworks.exe"
   ```

   to

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-texworks.exe" -stylesheet C:\Users\myusername\black-background.css
   ```
4. Click `OK`

Comment: Your answer is possibly out of date. `Shift` + `right click` doesn't give a "properties" option in Windows 10. However, it is easy to create a new shortcut with the string given, then when that shortcut opens, **pin** it to the taskbar.

Comment: What is the full list of available colors? I want something else than white.

Comment: Just want to add in step 3 above, put your path to the style sheet in quotation marks e.g. "C:\Users\myusername\black-background.css", as it wouldn't work on mine (windows 10) without them.

Comment: Is there a way to query TeXworks via the terminal, to know what the default path for the style sheet is? (That would be useful for people running any OS, not just Windows, and would avoid having to change the path to the style sheet every time one forgets it.)

Answer (score 16):

As the TeXworks manual says, TeXworks includes built-in support for Qt, and the application of Qt style sheets may be used to change the look of the TeXworks. By digging around a bit, I came up with this answer. First, set up your copy of TeXworks by pasting in the shortcut target

```
"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-texworks.exe" -stylesheet "C:\Users\myusername\black-background.css"
```

as described in the answer of I Like To Code.

Paste in this code into your css file:

```
QWidget { /* everything, basically */
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
    color: white;
}

QPushButton { /* buttons */
    background-color: #646464;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1.5pt;
    border-color: white;
    padding: 4px;
}

QPushButton:pressed { /* after you press the button */
    background-color: #818181;
}

QTableView {
   background-color: #424242;
   alternate-background-color: #424242;
   selection-background-color: #818181;
   font-color:#FFFFFF;
}

/* QComboBox refers to drop-down menus (such as when selecting pdfTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeTeX, etc.) */

QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QComboBox::drop-down { 
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 15px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: #EEEEEE;
    border-left-style: solid; /* just a single line */
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:on {
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}

/* QMenuBar refers to the menu at the top (File, Edit, etc.)
   QMenu::item refers to the items under the menu
 */

QMenu::item:selected { /* when user selects item using mouse or keyboard */
    background-color: #909090;
}

QMenuBar::item:pressed,  QMenuBar::item:selected {
    background: #909090;
}

QTextEdit { /* text editor */
    background-color: black;  
    color: white; 
}

QScrollBar:vertical { /* vertical scroll bar */
    background: #424242;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical { /* the part of the scroll bar that gets dragged*/
    background: #AAAAAA;
    min-height: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical { 
    /* this seems useless, but it is actually quite important- 
       it makes the scroll bar's background a uniform color instead
       of tiny dots, if it were removed. */
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar:horizontal { /* same thing, but horizontal */
    background: #424242;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:horizontal { /* etc. */
    background: #AAAAAA;
    min-width: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal { 
    background: none;
}

QTabBar::tab { /* tabs that lead to different displays (such as those under "Preferences") */
    background: #3A3A3A;
    border: #909090;
    padding: 2px 4px 6px 8px;
    /* now I can't remember how this padding works, but removing it leads to ugly tab designs*/
}

QTabBar::tab:hover {
    background: #818181;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
    background: #909090;
}
```

This results in a style that even fixes the line numbering text color and various menus:

[image: Dark-themed editor:]
[image: Dark-themed PDF Viewer]

Of course, you will want to change the colors of your syntax-patterns.txt (see [here as to how to do it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256425/91603)) to fit the black background. The code above does not *completely* fix TeXworks' editor style, but if you ask people with more experience with Qt Style Sheets, they may be able to help you better, or you can look in [the Qt Style Sheets example page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html) to customize it to your own preferences. The three main issues with this answer as it is now are that it does not completely change the color of the search menu, it does not show arrows in drop down menus, and the scroll bars seem to behave somewhat strangely. The images below illustrate these problems:

[image: search problem][image: drop-down menu problem]

[image: scroll-bar problem 1] → [image: scroll-bar problem 2]

Hopefully, this TeXworks style will suffice, even with its imperfections.

Answer (score 4):

Rather then explaining the steps which the other answers have already given (including a referenced answer by @Robert Zhang that has further reading), I will include the steps to reproduce my current TeXworks "dark mode" that I have implemented following on from the above answers, a GitHub `.css` file and my own edits.

This is how my current setup looks. I have added filler text, deleted commands and removed personal data as this is a current PhD document I am working on but I wanted to showcase the most common commands in the text editor like `\cite{}`, `\gls{}`, `$...$` etc):

[image]

First, the `.css` file that uses Qt modifications was obtained from a GitHub user @ezellohar who posted [their implementation of a dark mode `.css` file](https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/932#issuecomment-855469021) which I have used with a minor edit to the background code (`QTextEdit` `background-color: #000000;` in original, `: #010101` in mine) which I will post herein (all credit is to @ezellohar for the following code):

```
/* QWidget: main interface colors */
QWidget {
    background-color: #222222;
    selection-background-color: #555555;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    selection-color: white;
}

/* QTextEdit: the actual text editor window*/
QTextEdit {
    background-color: #010101;  /* EDIT HERE USING HEX CODE FROM A WEBSITE */
    color: white;
    selection-background-color: #555555;
    selection-color: white;
}


/* QComboBox refers to drop-down menus (such as when selecting pdfTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeTeX, etc.) */
QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 2px 18px 4px 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

/* drop-down: the arrow frame */
QComboBox::drop-down { 
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 20px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: #eeeeee;
    border-left-style: solid;
}

/* the menu once opened */
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border: 2px solid darkgray;
    selection-background-color: #333333;
    background-color: black;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(./res/downarrow.png);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:on {
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
}

/* QMenuBar refers to the menu at the top (File, Edit, etc.)
   QMenu::item refers to the items under the menu
 */
QMenu::item:selected {
    background-color: #333333;
}

QMenuBar::item:pressed,  QMenuBar::item:selected {
    background: #333333;
}

/*  QScrollBar: handles scroll bars. Must be doubled for vertical and horizontal
    handle is the moving part. add-line is the region where the arrow is drawn.
    If no image is embedded, the arrow is a dot.
*/
QScrollBar:vertical { 
    background: #111111;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background: #555555;
    min-height: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
     border: none;
     background: #333333;
     height: 20px;
     subcontrol-position: bottom;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
     border: none;
     background: #333333;
     height: 20px;
     subcontrol-position: top;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
 
QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical {
    image: url(./res/uparrow.png);
    border: none;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    padding: 12px;
}
QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    image: url(./res/downarrow.png);
    border: none;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    padding: 12px;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical { 
    /* this seems useless, but it is actually quite important- 
       it makes the scroll bar's background a uniform color instead
       of tiny dots, if it were removed. */
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar:horizontal {
    background: #111111;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background: #555555;
    min-width: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
     border: none;
     background: #333333;
    width: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
     border: none;
     background: #333333;
    width: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar:left-arrow:horizontal {
    image: url(./res/leftarrow.png);
    border: none;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    padding: 12px;
}
QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal {
    image: url(./res/rightarrow.png);
    border: none;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    padding: 12px;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal { 
    background: none;
}

/* QSizeGrip: corner image to resize window */
QSizeGrip {
    image: url(./res/sizegrip.png);
    background: none;
}

/* QTabWidget: the tab bar frame, needed for QTabBar styling */
QTabWidget::pane {
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}

QTabWidget::tab-bar {
    left: 5px; /* move to the right by 5px */
}

/* Buttons in prefs menu. It styles also the console close button if not specified*/
QTabWidget QToolButton {
    background-color: #444444;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 1px;
}

QTabWidget QToolButton:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
}

Tw--UI--ClosableTabWidget QToolButton {
    qproperty-icon: url(./res/close.png); /* empty image */
    background-color: #333333;
}
Tw--UI--ClosableTabWidget QToolButton:hover {
    background-color: #800000;
}

/* QTabBar: tabs (Preferences, console output) */
QTabBar::tab {
    background: #222222;
    border: 1px solid #555555;
    border-bottom-color: #333333; /* same as pane color */
    min-width: 8ex;
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
    background: #333333;
    color: #ffffff;
}

QTabBar::tab:hover {
    background: #444444;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
    border-color: #555555;
    border-bottom-color: #333333; /* same as pane color */
}

/* make non-selected tabs look smaller */
QTabBar::tab:!selected {
    margin-top: 2px;
}

/* QDockWidget: search results window*/
QDockWidget {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    titlebar-close-icon: url(./res/close.png);
    titlebar-normal-icon: url(./res/undock.png);
}

QDockWidget::title {
    text-align: left;
    background: #222222;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

QDockWidget::close-button, QDockWidget::float-button {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

QDockWidget::close-button:hover, QDockWidget::float-button:hover {
    background: #444444;
}

/* QHeaderView: search results header row */
QHeaderView::section  {
    background-color: #222222;
    border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
QHeaderView::section:hover  {
    background-color: #444444;
}

/* QTableView: search results rows */
QTableView {
   background-color: #111111;
   alternate-background-color: #222222;
   selection-background-color: #555555;
   font-color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* QToolButton: buttons with images (under menu) */
QToolButton:hover {
    background-color: #444444;
}

/* QPushButton: buttons with text (ok, cancel...) */
QPushButton {
    background-color: #222222;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #555555;
    padding: 4px;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #555555;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #555555;
    padding: 4px;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #444444;
}
```

The above was saved as `darkbg.css` in a known location, together with the "res" folder containing a set of necessary arrow icon images for the theme (available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F1TaAOLeZi76NWTCobP5wa-cgESC9JhO), as posted by @ezellohar). On my Windows 10, I have TeXworks (from TeX Live 2021) as a taskbar icon so right clicking the icon, then right clicking the name of the programme and then clicking on properties looks like this:

[image]

From the properties, the Target is modified as such (for my machine):

```
C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\texworks.exe -stylesheet "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Programming\LaTeX\CSS Styles\darkbg.css"
```

In general, Target is of this form:

```
path_to_texworks.exe -stylesheet "path_to_darkbg.css"
```

as mentioned above by [I Like to Code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383313/273733). This then sets the TeXworks theme to dark when clicking on the taskbar icon. To associate `.tex` files globally with the dark theme requires editing the registry (on Windows at least, other operating systems will be different). To append the dark theme `stylesheet` to all `.tex` files opened with TeXworks, follow [the answer to my question on superuser.SE](https://superuser.com/a/1747127/1735744) by @harrymc. In a brief summary in case that question/answer is lost, make a backup of your registry (very important!), run `regedit`, go to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TL.TeXworks.edit.2021\shell\open\command` (substitute the appropriate year for your installed version) and change the data field to something of this form:

```
"C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\texworks.exe" -stylesheet "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Programming\LaTeX\CSS Styles\darkbg.css" "%1"
```

The background darkness (which is quite black in my setup) can be changed with the line of `darkbg.css` that has been commented with `/* EDIT HERE USING HEX CODE FROM A WEBSITE */`.

The next step is to change the `syntax-pattern.txt` that sets the colours of latex commands, comments etc. The location of this file varies depending on whether you installed TeXwork with TeX Live, MiKTeX etc. but [it can be found here for Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256420/273733). On my system, [it was found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660136/273733):

```
C:\Users\[Your user]\.texlive2021\texmf-config\texworks\configuration\
```

It would be wise to copy and save the original `syntax-pattern.txt` file somewhere else so that you have a backup for if or when you want to revert back to non-dark mode. With the copy that still exists in `\texworks\configuration\`, open it and edit the colours for your particular TeX implementation (I use LaTeX but there are options for ConTeXt, BibTeX, LaTeX DTX and Lua in `syntax-pattern.txt`). My edited file to give the dark mode setup I am using consists of (the `[LaTeX]` options in my case):

```
# TeXworks: Patterns for syntax coloring

# Each entry consists of three whitespace-separated fields:
# <style> <spell?> <regex>

# <style> is a combination of color and style flags
# Valid syntax:
# <fgcolor>
# <fgcolor>/<bgcolor>
# ;<fontflags>
# <fgcolor>;<fontflags>
# <fgcolor>/<bgcolor>;<fontflags>
#
# The color fields <fgcolor> and <bgcolor> are either:
# *) a color name from the list defined in the SVG standard;
#    see https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords
# *) a hexadecimal color value of the form #rrggbb; note that if this is used at
#    the beginning of a line, a space " " must be added in front of it so the
#    line is not interpreted as a comment (e.g., " #aabbcc" instead of "#aabbcc")
#
# The <fontflags> field is a combination of the letters
# B (bold)
# I (italic)
# U (underlined)

# <spell> is a flag controlling whether this style is subject to spell-checking;
# "Y" or "y" for yes, "N" (or anything else, actually) for no.

# <regex> is the regular expression to match.

# Note that order of rules may be important if several rules could match at the same position;
# this is why the generic "control sequence" rule comes AFTER the specific \begin/\end one.

[LaTeX]
# special characters
springgreen N   [$#^_{}&]

# LaTeX environments
limegreen   N   \\(?:begin|end)\s*\{[^\}]*\}

# LaTeX packages
aqua        N   \\usepackage\s*(?:\[[^\]]*\]\s*)?\{[^\}]*\}

# control sequences
gold        N   \\(?:[\p{L}@]+|.)

# comments
crimson     Y   %.*

[ConTeXt]
# special characters
darkred     N   [$#{}&]

# 'other' special characters
darkblue    N   [=\[\]]

# mathematical operations
gray        N   [\-+/^_]

# start/stop
darkgreen;B N   \\(?:start|stop)[A-Za-z]+

# control sequences
blue;B      N   \\(?:[\p{L}@]+|.)

# comments
red     Y   %.*

[BibTeX]

# entries
darkgreen   N   @[^{]+

# comments
red     Y   %.*

# keys
blue    N   [a-zA-Z]+(?=\s*=)

[LaTeX DTX]

# comments
red     Y   \^\^A.*

# Guards
darkviolet      N   ^%<@@=[^>]*>
limegreen       N   ^%<\*[^>]*>
crimson     N   ^%</[^>]*>
brown       N   ^%<<
orange      N   ^%<[^>]*>

# special characters
darkred     N   \^\^\^\^\^[0-9a-z]{5}
darkred     N   \^\^\^\^[0-9a-z]{4}
darkred     N   \^\^\^[0-9a-z]{3}
darkred     N   \^\^[0-9a-z]{2}
darkred     N   [$#^_{}&]
gray        N   ^%%.*
gray        N   ^%

# Macrocode
lawngreen   N   \\(?:begin|end)\{macrocode\}

# LaTeX environments
lawngreen   N   \\(?:begin|end)\s*\{[^}]*\}

# control sequences
blue        N   \\(?:[\p{L}@:_]+|.)

[Lua]

# Comments (single line only)
red     Y   --.*

# Strings
green       N   (?:\"(?:[^\"\\]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\"|$)|\'(?:[^\'\\]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\'|$))
green       N   \[(=*)\[[\s\S]*(?:\]\1\]|$)

# Keywords
blue;B      N   
\b(?:and|break|do|else|elseif|end|false|for|function|if|in|local|nil|not|or|repeat|return|then|true|until|while)\b

# Numbers
darkblue    N   [+-]?(?:0x[\da-f]+|(?:(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d*)?)(?:e[+\-]?\d+)?))

# other possibilities to be added....
# [Metapost]
# etc
```

The colour names and appearance can be found from the website mentioned in the header of the [`syntax-pattern.txt` file](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords). The colours I chose (such as `gold` and `aqua`) are just to stand out the most and be as visually displeasing as possible, change them to what you would prefer.

To change the preview pane actual document to dark mode too (as a bright white page does defeat the purpose of dark mode slightly!), add the following to your document preamble from [this self question/answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660185/273733):

```
\pagecolor{black}\color{white}
```

That changes the text colour and page colour, but does not affect figure captions, table captions nor table headers or data. To change the captions text colour to white, add this to the preamble [(as pointed out by Gonzalo Medina)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132616/273733):

```
\usepackage[font={color=white}]{caption}
```

Table data and text will still appear black, so to change this (and using `tabularx` as an example table environment) add this to the preamble [(from this self question/answer)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660185/273733):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{\color{white}\arrayrulecolor{white}}
```

Which when put all together is just:

```
\usepackage[font={color=white}]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pagecolor{black}\color{white}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{\color{white}\arrayrulecolor{white}}
```

and add or change to whatever table environments you are using in your document.

With the package `listings`, to achieve dark mode (whilst removing language syntax highlighting) you can use:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{%
    \lstset{
        basicstyle=\color{white},
        backgroundcolor=\color{black},
        }%
     \color{white}%
     }
```

Which produces:

[image: lstlisting environment]

It would probably be best to separate the dark mode components of the PDF preview screen into a custom package like so:

```
\ProvidesPackage{customdarkmode}

\usepackage[font={color=white}]{caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\pagecolor{black}\color{white}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{\color{white}\arrayrulecolor{white}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{%
    \lstset{
        basicstyle=\color{white},
        backgroundcolor=\color{black},
        }%
     \color{white}%
     }
```

That can then either be imported with a full path in `\usepackage{}` (or just the package name but that either requires symbolic links to your `~\texmf-dist\tex\latex\` if you keep the package in another folder, putting into the `~\texmf-dist\tex\latex\` folder or placing the package in the same directory as the file you are running) and then commented out when needed to revert back to white paper/black text.

I haven't went as far to find out issues with other tables or environments but so far it looks good. Just remember to revert back to normal white paper/black text when you have a final version of the document.

This is how I have achieved dark mode with TeXworks and thanks to the answerers on here and GitHub for assisting, it is very appreciated.