# How to change background colour in texworks

Tags: texworks

I am using texworks for the first time, I want to change the background of the editor from dark to white, as the code is not visible in dark background. I am using texworks in Manjaro Linux on GNOME desktop environment. Please help me.

[image: editor background]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is also very simple to change the colors and keep the dark background.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383271/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texworks) can help you.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to changing the background color you may easily change the highlighting colors by altering the file `~/.TeXworks/configuration/syntax-patterns.txt`:

[image: dark theme]

```
[LaTeX]
# special characters
orangered               N       [\$#\^_\{\}&]

# LaTeX environments
lightseagreen        N       \\(?:begin|end)\s*\{[^\}]*\}

# LaTeX packages
lightskyblue       N       \\usepackage\s*(?:\[[^\]]*\]\s*)?\{[^\}]*\}

# control sequences
lightsteelblue               N       \\(?:[A-Za-z@]+|.)

# comments
grey                    Y       %.*
```