# How can I set a color to command highlighting in TeXworks?

Tags: texworks

I would like to have a darktheme in TeXworks, So I have followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383271/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texworks) answer. However, the default color of commands like `\section` is dark blue, which makes it very difficult to see (even worse for `\usepackage` which uses a darker blue).

Is there any way to define the special syntax coloring used within my CSS file?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452579/124577

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks! I would simply upvote your comment but don't have enough rep