# How to change the color of editor in Texworks

Tags: color, editors, texworks

I want to change the color from white to black in Texworks. The output pdf remain white, I means the editor back ground.

[image]

---

I can do it !! Thank you for letting me know:

***memorandum***

**1)** Make a `mystyle.css` as follows and put it in the file **which contains the** `texworks.exe`. In my case such directory located in `C:\texlive\2013\tlpkg\texworks`

```
QTextEdit {
    background-color: black;  
    color: white;            /* sets the main text color */
}

QWidget { /* everything, basically */
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
    color: white;
}

QPushButton { /* buttons */
    background-color: #646464;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1.5pt;
    border-color: white;
    padding: 4px;
}

QPushButton:pressed { /* after you press the button */
    background-color: #818181;
}

QTableView {
   background-color: #424242;
   alternate-background-color: #424242;
   selection-background-color: #818181;
   font-color:#FFFFFF;
}

/* QComboBox refers to drop-down menus (such as when selecting pdfTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeTeX, etc.) */

QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QComboBox::drop-down { 
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 15px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: #EEEEEE;
    border-left-style: solid; /* just a single line */
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:on {
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}

/* QMenuBar refers to the menu at the top (File, Edit, etc.)
   QMenu::item refers to the items under the menu
 */

QMenu::item:selected { /* when user selects item using mouse or keyboard */
    background-color: #909090;
}

QMenuBar::item:pressed,  QMenuBar::item:selected {
    background: #909090;
}

QTextEdit { /* text editor */
    background-color: black;  
    color: white; 
}

QScrollBar:vertical { /* vertical scroll bar */
    background: #424242;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical { /* the part of the scroll bar that gets dragged*/
    background: #AAAAAA;
    min-height: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical { 
    /* this seems useless, but it is actually quite important- 
       it makes the scroll bar's background a uniform color instead
       of tiny dots, if it were removed. */
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar:horizontal { /* same thing, but horizontal */
    background: #424242;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:horizontal { /* etc. */
    background: #AAAAAA;
    min-width: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal { 
    background: none;
}

QTabBar::tab { /* tabs that lead to different displays (such as those under "Preferences") */
    background: #3A3A3A;
    border: #909090;
    padding: 2px 4px 6px 8px;
    /* now I can't remember how this padding works, but removing it leads to ugly tab designs*/
}

QTabBar::tab:hover {
    background: #818181;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
    background: #909090;
}
```

**2)** On the command prompt, **move** into a directory which contains `texworks.exe`.

In my case, to move such directory, I execute the code `cd C:\texlive\2013\tlpkg\texworks` in the Command prompt. Then the command prompt will be as follows;
`C:\texlive\2013\tlpkg\texworks>`

**3)** To open the texworks reflecting the `mystyle.css`, execute the code `TeXWorks -stylesheet=./mystyle.css`on the command prompt **on the directory explained 2)**.

In my case, in the command line will be the following :

`C:\texlive\2013\tlpkg\texworks>TeXWorks -stylesheet=./mystyle.css`

**4)** With an error about path launch, but the texworks open with black background.

**5)** Further more, by replacing the `syntax-patterns.txt` located in `C:\Users\User\TeXworks\configuration` (my case) with the following one, we can get more comfortable visual:

contents for new  `syntax-patterns.txt`:

```
# Each entry consists of three whitespace-separated fields:

# <style> <spell?> <regex>



# <style> is a combination of color and style flags

# Valid syntax:

# <fgcolor>

# <fgcolor>/<bgcolor>

# ;<fontflags>

# <fgcolor>;<fontflags>

# <fgcolor>/<bgcolor>;<fontflags>

#

# The color fields <fgcolor> and <bgcolor> are either:

# *) a color name from the list defined in the SVG standard;

#    see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords

# *) a hexadecimal color value of the form #rrggbb; note that if this is used at

#    the beginning of a line, a space " " must be added in front of it so the

#    line is not interpreted as a comment (e.g., " #aabbcc" instead of "#aabbcc")

#

# The <fontflags> field is a combination of the letters

# B (bold)

# I (italic)

# U (underlined)



# <spell> is a flag controlling whether this style is subject to spell-checking;

# "Y" or "y" for yes, "N" (or anything else, actually) for no.



# <regex> is the regular expression to match.



# Note that order of rules may be important if several rules could match at the same position;

# this is why the generic "control sequence" rule comes AFTER the specific \begin/\end one.



[LaTeX]

# special characters

# PURPLE

 #ae8ef0    N   [$#^_{}&] 



# LaTeX environments

# ORANGE

 #dc861f;I  N   \\(?:begin|end)\s*\{[^}]*\} 



# LaTeX packages

# PINK

 #ec4271;I  N   \\usepackage\s*(?:\[[^]]*\]\s*)?\{[^}]*\}



# control sequences

# LIGHTBLUE

 #5dd4ef    N   \\(?:[A-Za-z@]+|.) 



# comments

# DARKBROWN

 #797666;I  Y   %.* 



[ConTeXt]

# special characters

# PURPLE

 #ae8ef0    N   [$#^_{}&] 



# start/stop

# ORANGE

 #dc861f;I  N   \\(?:start|stop)[A-Za-z]+ 



# control sequences

# LIGHTBLUE

 #5dd4ef    N   \\(?:[A-Za-z@]+|.) 



# comments

# DARKBROWN

 #797666;I  Y   %.* 



# other possibilities to be added....

# [BibTeX]

# [Metapost]

# etc
```

**6)** To open by double click on the `texworks.exe`,

1. `shiht`+`right click` on the `texworks.exe`
2. Click `property`
3. Change the path: In my case I changed 
   from `C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\texworks.exe`
   to   `C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\texworks.exe -stylesheet=C:\texlive\2013\tlpkg\texworks/mystyle.css`

   Then by double click on the `texworks.exe` instead terminal, we can open TeXworks reflected above color change.

If we open `texworks.exe` by its short cut button, then the procedure **6)** is required for each short cut button instead of `texworks.exe`.

Ref:
[How can I set a dark theme in TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383271/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texworks)

The result is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Possibly related? [How can I set a dark theme in TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383271/134144)

Comment: What has your reference link to do with your question? The screenshot show TeXworks instead of TeXstudio.

Comment: I am not sure where I should put the css file and how reflect it. To tell the truth I changed the color of backgraund in my old computer. I buy a new one, then I am not sure where should I put file.