# How to put an in-text DOI citation in a box to reduce space within the beamer document class?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, parbox

I have created a custom `\citedoi{}` command based off `biblatex`'s `\citeurl{}` command that is working fine. I can then put the `\citedoi{}` within a box near images or other things that need citations that are not in-text. I have tried to create a `parbox` to contain the `doi` in-text so it consumes the least amount of space (the font size is `\tiny` and it takes too much space within a line as can be seen in the images). I want to wrap the `doi` within a box over two `\tiny` lines so that it reduces the space between the prior and after words.

The motivation for this is that my PhD supervisor likes to have the `doi`'s at the immediate location in addition to a bibliography at the end of presentation slides. I created a command to use for annotating purposes `\scitedoi{}` and the failed `\itcitedoi{}` for use within text:

```
\newcommand\scitedoi[1]{{\color{blue}\tiny\citedoi{#1}}}
\newcommand\itcitedoi[1]{\parbox{1.5cm}{\color{blue}\tiny\citedoi{#1}}}
```

When using just `\scitedoi{}` the `beamer` frame looks like this:

[image: How the doi currently looks]

When also using the `\itcitedoi{}` command it goes off into the margin:

[image: parbox attempt]

Ideally, I would like for the `\itcitedoi{}` command to be treated as text (if that makes sense?) and for text to go around it as it normally would for a word. I know that the text, even being `\tiny`, will increase the gap between lines where used but this is fine.

Does anyone know how I can achieve putting the `\citedoi{}` within a box that spans and wraps the `doi` over two `\tiny` lines using `parbox` or anything similar please?

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{ref.bib}
@Article{M2020,
  author = {Mehandia, Seema and Sharma, S. C. and Arya, Shailendra Kumar},
  journal = {Biotechnol. Rep. (Amst)},
  title = {Isolation and characterization of an alkali and thermostable laccase},
  doi = {10.1016/j.btre.2019.e00413},
}
@Article{Mn2009,
  author = {Murugesan, Kumarasamy and Kim, Young-Mo and Jeon, Jong-Rok and Chang, Yoon-Seok},
  journal = {J Hazard Mater.},
  title = {Effect of metal ions on reactive dye decolorization by laccase from Ganoderma lucidum.},
  doi = {10.1016/j.jhazmat.2009.02.075},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[hyperref={colorlinks=false}]{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xurl}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

% Custom \citedoi command adapted from \citeurl
\DeclareFieldFormat{citedoi}{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citedoi}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield[citedoi]{doi}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcommand\scitedoi[1]{{\color{blue}\tiny\citedoi{#1}}}

\newcommand\itcitedoi[1]{\parbox{1.5cm}{\color{blue}\tiny\citedoi{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Unreproducible}
This text is just text and nothing more as I just need filler text \scitedoi{M2020} that spans a few lines on 
this beamer presentation. This text is just text and nothing more \itcitedoi{Mn2009} as I just need filler text 
that spans a few lines on this beamer presentation. This text is just text and nothing more as I just need filler 
text that spans a few lines on this beamer presentation. 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am compiling with:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
```

Comment: Just an idea: try using a QR code.

Comment: @OlegLobachev I have implemented a solution using QR codes that I am really happy with, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: sorry to answer you here but I couldn't find a way to contact you since I cant comment under your comment (missing reputation). I read your answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383271/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texworks) and I think that style looks awesome! My only problem is if I change anything in my style-patterns.txt file it won't change anything in my editor! Again, sorry to have to answer you under this post but maybe you have an idea?

Comment: @Athena hey sorry for the delay in replying, it depends on how you're doing it and probably the OS you're using, are you removing the original unedited style-patterns.txt from the folder? It should load it automatically, that's what it did with mine, I'm using TeXworks version 0.6.6 on Windows 10 - maybe there is an issue with Linux/Mac and I could improve the answer if you can provide more details please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the effect you get in the MWE is exactly what you want to achieve, but you'll want to use `\nolinkurl` in your field format for `citedoi`. Otherwise LaTeX is unable to offer line breaks inside the DOI, because it cannot be hyphenated like normal words.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={colorlinks=false}]{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xurl}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citedoi}{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citedoi}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield[citedoi]{doi}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcommand\scitedoi[1]{{\color{blue}\tiny\citedoi{#1}}}
\newcommand\itcitedoi[1]{\parbox{1.5cm}{\color{blue}\tiny\citedoi{#1}}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{M2020,
  author  = {Mehandia, Seema and Sharma, S. C.
             and Arya, Shailendra Kumar},
  journal = {Biotechnol. Rep. (Amst)},
  title   = {Isolation and characterization of an alkali
             and thermostable laccase},
  doi     = {10.1016/j.btre.2019.e00413},
}
@article{Mn2009,
  author  = {Murugesan, Kumarasamy and Kim, Young-Mo
             and Jeon, Jong-Rok and Chang, Yoon-Seok},
  journal = {J Hazard Mater.},
  title   = {Effect of metal ions on reactive dye decolorization
             by laccase from Ganoderma lucidum.},
  doi     = {10.1016/j.jhazmat.2009.02.075},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Unreproducible}
This text is just text and nothing more as I just need filler text \scitedoi{M2020} that spans a few lines on 
this beamer presentation. This text is just text and nothing more \itcitedoi{Mn2009} as I just need filler text 
that spans a few lines on this beamer presentation. This text is just text and nothing more as I just need filler 
text that spans a few lines on this beamer presentation. 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Three-line DOI.]

Comment: I did not know of that option `\nolinkurl`, I think I should read the `biblatex` manual more thoroughly next time, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @moewe answered my question but I also want to add an answer showing the suggestion by @Oleg Lobachev to use QR codes with the `qrcode` package. Adapting the [answer by Martin H](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18578/273733) to calculate the text height (so to make a QR code with an appropriate height) gives this as the output:

[image]

with a hyperlinked QR code set to the text height. Thanks for the suggestion and thanks for the accepted answer, both are useful for my needs.

```
% arara: pdflatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{ref.bib}
@Article{M2020,
  author = {Mehandia, Seema and Sharma, S. C. and Arya, Shailendra Kumar},
  journal = {Biotechnol. Rep. (Amst)},
  title = {Isolation and characterization of an alkali and thermostable laccase},
  doi = {10.1016/j.btre.2019.e00413},
}
@Article{Mn2009,
  author = {Murugesan, Kumarasamy and Kim, Young-Mo and Jeon, Jong-Rok and Chang, Yoon-Seok},
  journal = {J Hazard Mater.},
  title = {Effect of metal ions on reactive dye decolorization by laccase from Ganoderma lucidum.},
  doi = {10.1016/j.jhazmat.2009.02.075},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[hyperref={colorlinks=false}]{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

% Custom \qrdoi command adapted from \citeurl following the suggestion by Oleg Lobachev

\DeclareFieldFormat{qrdoi}{\qrcode{https://doi.org/#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\qrdoi}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield[qrdoi]{doi}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcommand\scitedoi[1]{{\color{blue}\tiny\citedoi{#1}}}

\newcommand\itcitedoi[1]{(\parbox{1.5cm}{\color{blue}\tiny\citedoi{#1}})}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Unreproducible}

\newlength{\myl}
\settoheight{\myl}{test text}
\qrset{link, height=1.5\myl}

This text is just text and nothing more as I just need filler text that spans a few lines on (\qrdoi{M2020})
this beamer presentation. This text is just text and nothing more as I just need filler text 
that spans a few lines on this beamer presentation. This text is just text and nothing more as I just need filler 
text that spans a few lines on this beamer presentation. 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

There is probably a better or more recent method to calculate the text height but this works.